# SharePoint 2010 restore - list does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, restore

I restored a **SharePoint 2010** SQL **database** to my development environment using **restore** option of **SQL Server Management Studio**.

I'm able to read the lists, documents etc., but I am unable to upload or create a new item.

I get this error:

> List does not exist

Any ideas?

Comment: Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Database level principals that allow an entity to connect to a SQL Server database. Users are associated with logins via SIDs, creating a relationship between the two and allowing a login to connect to the instance and then use the associated user to connect to the database.
What commonly happens with SQL authenticated logins and database users on a restore is that the SIDS will be out of sync, thus breaking the relationship. This relationship must be repaired before you can connect to the database using that login, because in the eyes of SQL Server those principals are no longer connected. You can fix this with the following SQL:

```
ALTER USER [foo] WITH LOGIN=[foo]
```

You can use the following query in the context of your database to check for orphans:
select

```
    dp.name [user_name]
    ,dp.type_desc [user_type]
    ,isnull(sp.name,'Orhphaned!') [login_name]
    ,sp.type_desc [login_type]
from   
    sys.database_principals dp
    left join sys.server_principals sp on (dp.sid = sp.sid)
where
    dp.type in ('S','U','G')
    and dp.principal_id >4
order by sp.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Muskan. I'm unable to understand the problem. I just restored the database to a new machine. Please help me in understanding what went wrong in this process?